# Windows 10 upgrade - how delate this update?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I allowed Windows 10 update on my Windows 7.

Later I wanted to stop this update.

Right now I have Windows 7 as desired, but I guess, that win10 update is on my drive, because I have got 10gb of free space, and now 4 gb.

Where can I find downloaded files of Windows 10 update, and delete them?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to look in the `%temp%` directory.
Else you can use a program called **WinDirStat** to look for the files that are taking the missing space.

**WinDirStat** can be downloaded [here](https://windirstat.info/download.html), and it is free software published under the GNU General Public License, version 2.

Comment: Glad to see you jumping right in to help. Unfortunately, this does not answer the question. Suggestions should be made in the comment area. When you have gained enough reputation you will be able to post comments on other people's questions.

Comment: @CharlieRB I don't know the program WinDirStat, but maybe it is able in a general case to search for and find the files that are using the missing space... and I cannot know which files are (and where they are) on the OP computer...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).  So everyone understands, this is an automatically submitted comment when an answer is voted to be deleted due to quality issues, in this particular case I have submitted it manually due to quality concerns.

Answer (score 0):

enable *view hidden files* and *protected system file* in **folder and search option**> **View** tab >  in **organize** drop down menu of windows explorer.
check the size of these folders

**C:\$windows.~BT**

**C:\$Windows.~WS**

these folder holds the installation media for winodws 10 upgrade. you can safely delete them.

Revert your folder and search option changes after this.